# Error to compile ios project with kotlin multiplatform

Tags: xcode, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have implemented kotlin multiplatform in an existing ios project and I have these problems

When I compile the application for the simulator an error occurs in the build phases script.

[image]

[image]

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

When I remove the script the compiled for simulator works . I can run the simulator

Another error is when I want to archive the project. Says it was built for iOS simulator

[image]

My build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0")
}

configurations {
    create("compileClasspath")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

val libName = "shared"

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries.framework(libName)
    }

    val coroutinesVersion = "1.4.1-native-mt"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC"
    val ktorVersion = "1.4.0"
    val sqlDelightVersion = "1.4.3"
    val reactive_version = "1.1.18"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")

                // Coroutines
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.2")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")

                //  KTOR
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")

                // SQLDELIGHT
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelightVersion")

                // Reactive
                implementation("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:$reactive_version")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")

                implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")

                implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.2")

                // HTTP
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }

        all {
            languageSettings.apply {
                progressiveMode = true
                useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
                useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi")
            }
        }
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)

sqldelight {
    database("SmileduDataBase") {
        packageName = "com.example.smiledu"
        schemaOutputDirectory = file("src/commonMain/db/databases")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Another error is when I want to archive the project. Says it was built for iOS simulator
```

Hi. I faced this issue a few times and the only work around I got is that we need to run this `./gradlew clean` in android studio terminal before creating an archive for iOS and then try to create archive and it should work. You can find more details on this here :- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40907

```
When I compile the application for the simulator an error occurs in the build phases script.
```

For this  it looks like your wrapper is corrupted probably am not so sure about this. Does android app runs perfectly ? Also you can have a look here once :- [How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57881202/how-to-resolve-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappe)

Comment: Hi. It worked. Thank you!  The android app does work and now the ios app too. I had to run $ gradle wrapper

Comment: But when i submitting my app this error occurs "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Smiledu_app.app/Frameworks/shared.framework/shared' is not permitted." ☹️

Comment: It would be great if you can share some more details for the above issue I haven't faced this anytime at least till now.

Comment: Hi. Here I detailed it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244025/kotlin-multiplatform-error-itms-90171-invalid-bundle-structure