# When I try to run ./gradlew genSources for a minecraft mod I wanna make is just pops out the error thingamapop

Tags: gradle, gradlew, minecraft-fabric

When I run `./gradlew genSources` for a Minecraft mod I wanna make it pops out this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

and this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Could someone tell me and help me as to how to fix it. I am using Visual Studio Code on a Windows 11 PC. Please help me.

I tried to run `./gradlew genSources` and it would just pop out an error.

Comment: Does the gradle executable file, `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`, exist on your machine?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57881202/how-to-resolve-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappe

Comment: Yes it does. And its not 0kb.

Comment: Both in the mod I am trying to make and in my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found. I Found the answer and it was because I had my pc on Greece the Desktop that the folder of the mod was in is called Υπολογιστής and gradle/gradlew recognize that as some random caracters and all i had to do was change the folders directory form Desktop to Documents. Thank everyone that send an answer.