# Gradle "Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain" in Flutter project on Debian OS

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter project on Debian OS. Despite having all the necessary Gradle Wrapper files and manually downloading Gradle version 8.5, I'm still facing the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Here are some details about my project setup:

Gradle Wrapper files are present (gradle-wrapper.properties, gradlew, gradlew.bat).
Gradle version 8.5 has been manually downloaded.
Running flutter doctor shows no issues and mentions a Debian OS.
File permissions seem appropriate (chmod +x gradlew has been executed).

I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot:

Cleaned the Gradle cache using ./gradlew clean.
Manually downloaded Gradle 8.5 and updated the gradle-wrapper.properties file.
Checked for Java version compatibility.
Ensured firewall and antivirus settings allow Gradle access to the internet.
Updated Flutter to the latest version using flutter channel stable and flutter upgrade.
Deleted the gradle directory and gradlew files, then ran flutter doctor again.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

OS: Debian
Flutter Version: [sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0']
Gradle Version: 8.5

please help me

Comment: `gradlew clean` doesn't clear Gradles cache, but probably that's not necessary. Did you follow the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) to add the Gradle wrapper with `gradle wrapper` with the help of a local installation of Gradle once to your project?

Comment: yes i did that
my flutter project contain all the necessary files but i don't know where is the problem it's the second day of trying

Comment: See if it can be fixed by the solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897185/1703730.